# Conformal representation

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation, quasiconformal-maps

[Complex analysis question]

I'm not sure if it is even possible to do conformal representation of function G to G*, since I need to transform one circle (line is circle with infinite radius) to two circles that interact.

If anyone can give me some opinion about this, it would be great since I don't have any clue how to do it and therefore I think it is even impossible.

Given functions;

$G = {y ≤ x}$ in $G^* = \{|z−i| > √2, |z + i| < √2\} $

Comment: it's possible to do stuff like |z-i|<=1 U |z+i|<1 because it has a single vertex, but here is has two vertices, at -1 and 1.

Comment: $\{z: y \leq x\}$ is not an open set. If the question is about mapping $G = \{z: y < x\}$ to $G^* = \{z: |z - i| > \sqrt 2 \land |z + i| < \sqrt 2\}$, take an appropriate branch of the square root to map $G$ to a sector bounded by two orthogonal rays. Then $z \mapsto (a - z)/(a + z)$ maps the sector to a region bounded by two orthogonal circles intersecting at $−1$ and $1$. Choose a value of $a$ that gives $G^∗$.